# migration to grails 4 error in liquibase CommonsLoggingLiquibaseLogger

Tags: spring-boot, grails, liquibase

i use grails version 3.3.4 and i want to migrate to new version of grails 4.0.1 and i'm having some issues with liquibase.

i made some changes in build.gradle i changed some versions

```
dependencies {  
    classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:3.0.10"
    classpath "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.4" 
}
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.0.4'
    compile ("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.3") {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework'
   }
}
```

**have the exception:**

```
    ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/liquibase/CommonsLoggingLiquibaseLogger
        at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.configureLiquibase(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:97)
        at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.doWithSpring(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:50)
        at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:539)
        at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:166)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:171)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:125)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:97)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:458)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:445)
        at ogrh4.Application.main(Application.groovy:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.liquibase.CommonsLoggingLiquibaseLogger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why are you excluding spring framework?

Comment: i was trying if it will work if i exclude spring because the exception was about spring. i googled more and i found the solution is to change the version of plugin of migration:      `compile "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"'`